# How to generate current url with different locales in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to generate current url with different locales as `hreflang` tags on every page and for each language. For example, for `example.com/es/category/general` I would like to generate this hreflangs in my `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="example.com/category/general" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="example.com/es/category/general" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="example.com/de/category/general" />
```

Currently, I set locale via prefix. Notice that for default `en` locale I don't use the prefix:

```
Route::prefix(parseLocale())->group(function () {
... // all routes go here
}

function parseLocale()
{
    $locale = request()->segment(1);
    $locales = config('app.available_locales');
    $default = config('app.fallback_locale');
    if ($locale !== $default && in_array($locale, $locales)) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        return $locale;
    }
    return;
}
```

How can I generate correct `hreflang` tags for each locale?

Comment: In case you don't want to program all by yourself, I use this package "mcamara/laravel-localization" that provides a helper function for returning localized urls.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a `blade` directive to generate the `hreflang` tags for each locale, in each page:

```
@foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $locale)
   @if ($locale == app()->getLocale())
      <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $locale }}" href="{{ url()->current() }}" />
   @else
      @if ($locale == config('app.fallback_locale'))
         <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $locale }}" href="{{ url('/') . request()->segments() }}" />
      @else
         <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $locale }}" href="{{ url('/') . $locale . request()->segments() }}" />
      @endif
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: For `example.com/es/category/general` I have `hreflang=example.com/es/es/category/general` (double prefix)

Comment: The answer has been edited to address the issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a bit more complex that I thought, because I don't use a prefix for default language. I decided to create a custom Service Provider and return an array with locales associated with URLs for these locales (I will also use this array for the language switcher component):

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        $languageUrls = [];

        $currentLocale = request()->segment(1);
        $locales = config('app.available_locales'); // ['en', 'de', 'es']
        $defaultLocale = config('app.fallback_locale'); // 'en'

        // Remove language prefix if not default from segments
        if ($currentLocale !== $defaultLocale && in_array($currentLocale, $locales)) {
            $noPrefixSegments = request()->segments();
            array_shift($noPrefixSegments);
            $noPrefixSegments = implode('/', $noPrefixSegments);
        }
        // Keep all segments
        else {
            $noPrefixSegments = request()->segments();
            $noPrefixSegments = implode('/', $noPrefixSegments);
        }

        // Generate an array of locales associated with URLs
        foreach ($locales as $locale) {
            if ($locale === $defaultLocale) {
                $languageUrls[$locale] = $noPrefixSegments;
            } else {
                $languageUrls[$locale] =  $locale . '/' . $noPrefixSegments;
            }
        }

        return $view->with('languageUrls', $languageUrls);
    });
}
```

Then in the blade template I simply generate all hreflangs:

```
@foreach ($languageUrls as $language => $url)
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $language }}" href="{{ url('/') }}/{{ $url }}" />
@endforeach
```

which for `https://example.com/es/category/page` gives me what I've expected:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/category/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/category/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/category/page" />
```